# Use redux function after refresh token JWT

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt, axios

I have functions

```
export function configureInterceptors(store) {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        if (error.response.status === 401 && err.config) {
          const originalRequest = error.config;
          originalRequest._retry = true;

          store.dispatch(jwtRefresh(originalRequest))          
        }
        throw error;
      }
    }
  );
}
```

```
export const jwtRefresh = (originalRequest) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(jwtRefreshBegins());

  axios
    .post('auth/jwt/refresh/', {
      refresh: window.localStorage.getItem('refresh')
    })
    .then(response => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', response.data.access);
      originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `JWT ${response.data.access}`;
      return axios(originalRequest)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
      window.localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    })
};
```

But all of my requests are in redux function. How can I make redux function again if refresh token was success? I must use redux function, because it change redux state.

Comment: What do you want to do excatly ? Do you want to update the redux state after api success ?

Comment: Yes, I wanna update redux state, but I have used a lot of actions and it's bad way to write redux action in then block of axios with refresh

Comment: It seems like you should dispatch an action with a constant which reducer can understand when you got the data from api. And why do you think it is bad to fire an action in then block ? I think you can dispatch it from anywhere if you have the right data.

Comment: I think it's bad way becuase app has almost 70 routes. One route use 5-15 redux actions. In this way I must execute redux action based on URL and use the same actions as in the components.